# C# equivalent of Java 'implements' keyword?

Tags: c#, java

In Java if you were to have the statement:

```
public class MyClass implements LargerClass {
```

Would you be extending the LargerClass with more methods?

What would be the equivalent of this class definition in C#?

I ask because I am not very familiar with Java and am currently converting some Java code to C# code and this one is giving me some trouble.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

```
public class MyClass implements LargerClass
```

In Java, this declares that `MyClass` implements the [interface](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) `LargerClass`; that is, sets out implementations for the behaviours defined in `LargerClass`.

To [inherit](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html) from another class in Java, use `extends`, e.g.

```
public class MyClass extends LargerClass
```

The C# equivalent, in both cases, is specified as

```
public class MyClass : LargerClass
```

Since this syntax doesn't make it clear whether or not `LargerClass` is an interface or another class being inherited, you'll find C#/.NET developers adopt the convention that interface names are prefixed with uppercase "I", e.g. `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I like this answer better because it mentions the standard convention you can use to differentiate between interfaces and classes.

Comment: In java that convention is conventionally used too.

Answer (score 8):

```
public class MyClass : LargerClass
{

}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class MyClass : LargerClass {...}
```